# Django form - keep some POST data

Tags: django

I am writing small django internet store and I have encountered a problem. Namely, I would like print list of the products (I need pruduct id) and also some form to buy them on the same page.

```
def order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # POST data processing
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/cart/')
    else:
        form = OrderForm()

    # here I would like to also use product_id from POST to generate products 
    # that have such id
    return render(request, 'order.html', {
        'form': form, 'products': products,
    })
```

But when I wrongly submit form, OrderForm() is called and then I lose my id. 
Any hints how to solve this problem (maybe keep somewhere that id)?

Edit: my store is used to rent some products on given time and adding product to cart means that I create new object rent that store information when product has been reserved by user

Model:

```
class Rent(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

    paid = models.BooleanField()
    begin_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)

    begin_hour = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, default=00)
    end_hour = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, default=24)
```

And OrderForm

```
class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    begin_date = forms.DateField(label='date', required=True,
                                   widget=extras.widgets.SelectDateWidget(years=range(2013, 2015)))
    end_date = forms.DateField(required=True, initial=datetime.date.today,
                                widget=extras.widgets.SelectDateWidget(years=range(2013, 2015)))
    begin_hour = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=((str(x), x) for x in range(0, 25)))
    end_hour = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=(((str(x)), x) for x in range(0, 25)))
```

Comment: Does `OrderForm` represent an object in the database? If so, please post the form's definition and the model's definition.

Comment: I have updated my question. OrderForm indirectly represent an object in the database

Comment: Where in your form you get the product id? I don't see where in the definition.

Comment: Normally forms keep their values, but I see that you don't have product id field in your `OrderForm`. You can use [request.session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#examples) to keep your custom values across requests. Or you can pass product_id to your render context and manually assign it to your form's input in template file.

Comment: @gatto Thank you for your help. I tried the second way and it works. Maybe it is not too elegant, but it works. I will also try to use sessions. Once again, thank a lot!!

Comment: @JosephConrad, But why not add product_id to the `OrderForm`?

Comment: BTW, you have an awesome nickname! `Joseph Conrad` is a great writer.